# NegativeScreen's custom multi-monitor version crashing on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, crash, accessibility

https://0.x2a.yt/other/private/NegativeScreen-custom-multi-monitor.exe ([mirror 1](https://github.com/mlaily/NegativeScreen/files/4645953/NegativeScreen-custom-multi-monitor.zip), [mirror 2](https://archive.org/details/negative-screen)) is crashing on my Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate (Aero disabled) when it starts. What could be the reason? The normal `NegativeScreen.exe` works fine.

[image]

```
Description:
  Stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: EY3SHVBFXSRNSBGKSV3CUAYHN3UGWWFA
  Problem Signature 02: 1.11.5008.36765
  Problem Signature 03: 5239010a
  Problem Signature 04: NegativeScreen
  Problem Signature 05: 1.11.5008.36765
  Problem Signature 06: 5239010a
  Problem Signature 07: 53
  Problem Signature 08: 112
  Problem Signature 09: System.Exception
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I attached a debugger and figured out that the program cannot register the hotkey <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

On my system, that hotkey was already registered by Microsoft OneNote. Disabling OneNote made the tool work. I am referring to this tray icon:

[image: OneNote in System Tray]

Newer versions of NegativeScreen show a warning and do not crash. However, they do not have the feature of inverting a single screen.

[image: Warning]