# How can I prevent Windows 10 from flashing white when displaying a window?

Tags: windows-10, dark-mode

I use Windows 10 with dark mode on. Windows 10 often flashes white when displaying a window, e.g.:

[image]

In this demo, I minimized and restored the window a few times: when restoring the window, a white screen sometimes appears.

How can I prevent Windows 10 from flashing white when displaying a window?

---

All animations are disabled:

[image]

I use a GS76 Stealth 11UH laptop (4k monitor) running on Microsoft Windows 10 with a 1080p external monitor. The white flash occurs in whichever monitor the window appears. Settings of each monitor:

[image]

Monitor 1 (4k):

[image]

[image]

Monitor 2 (1080p):

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/troubleshoot-screen-flickering-in-windows-47d5b0a7-89ea-1321-ec47-dc262675fc7b

Comment: @Gantendo thanks, I don't think it's screen flickering. Just white screen displayed waiting for the window to load.

Comment: @Gantendo In the demo, I minimized and restored the window a few times: when restoring the window, a white screen sometimes appears.

Comment: Have you tried disabling some of the window animation effects? https://www.pcworld.com/article/423950/how-to-disable-window-animations-in-windows-10.html

Comment: @DrMoishePippik thanks, yes all animations are disabled.

Comment: **I wasn't able to reproduce this on my machine.**  What is the resolution settings of the display? I obviously use Dark Mode

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, added to the question.

Comment: Did you think about achieving dark mode from white mode using NegativeScreen tool? It is not suitable for entertainment, but for productivity, it is much more efficient than dark mode created by apps devs due to its flexibility.

Comment: @miroxlav thanks, had a few issues with it https://superuser.com/q/1553920/116475 ; https://superuser.com/q/1553010/116475 but indeed I could try

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt – I see. Both linked issues now appear to be with quite an old software. Since the tool is just calling Windows Magnifier API, it is possible that it stands and falls upon it. My only issue was collision with Lenovo Vantage app, namely its enabled red filter, since it does similar trick using the same API :) I am using white mode for all apps when there is a bright day and various dark modes in the evening. I mapped it to easily reachable extra key on my keyboard (calculator) and also to Win+Left Click what is convenient when doing only mouse work :) AutoHotKey is the mapper

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is just the way Windows is designed and a result of the subpar implementation of dark mode.

You see, when you open a new window, Windows first draws that space with a white background as a buffer before displaying the actual content. Probably when they first designed it that way, they did not predict the necessity for something like dark mode years later.

You should only see this with win32 apps. The modern apps are designed with dark mode in mind and they don't suffer from this issue.